# How can I redeclare a method with same name but with our code in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two JS library File and they have same method . I need JSZip method in JSZip file . but when ı declare JSZip method . İt see xlsx.min.js file

How can I redeclare this function with my code to be executed.

```
declare var JSZip: any;


 static getKMLContentFromKMZ(file: File) {
//let JSZip: any;
return JSZip.loadAsync(file)
    .then(function (zip: any) {
        return zip.files['doc.kml'].async('string')
            .then(function (fileContent: any) {
                return fileContent;
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are asking; the grammar and formatting are confusing.  Please review the guidelines for [ask] a good question.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm not seeing how this relates to [tag:angularjs]?  It's a stretch, but this *might* relate to [tag:angular] since that is primarily written in typescript, where angularjs is not, but even then, I'm not seeing anything angular specific here either.....

Comment: Firstly my english not good . Sorry for that . I have two  JS File and they have same method . I need  JSZip method in JSZip file . but when ı declare JSZip method . İt see xlsx.min.js file

Comment: @MehmetResulAkyuz I dont kno if I understand the question, but if you have a .min.js file, then you must reference that file exactly for it to work..

Comment: I have two JS file. 
they are xlsx.min.js and JSZip.js .  I need JSZip method but They have same method. So I need JSZip method in the JSZip.js file @RicardoFerreira

Comment: @MehmetResulAkyuz your question is not so clear. Its not about the english is about what you really want. As far as I understood you want to implement a method that already exists but you want to override the existent method? If yes, why?

Comment: There is never a good reason to duplicate function names that are scoped within the same `class`. You're using a `static` but are telling us you're hitting name collisions, which implies that the `class` name is the same as well. Rethink your structure